# Android TimePicker returning the current minute instead of selected minute

Tags: android, android-timepicker

I have the following code that is from the Android dev website. The timepicker is intialized to the current time, which is fine. when i select a new time the hours are correct but the minutes always return the current time's minutes.

eg if it is 15:30 now and i select 16:45, the picker will return 16:30.
I have placed log statements inside onTimeSet and the minutes that are logged are the ones i select. when i pass these to the DateTime constructor, somehow the minutes are the current time's minutes.

does anyone know what is going on here?

thanks

```
public static class TimePickerFromFragment extends DialogFragment
            implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

            // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
            return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
                    DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
        }

        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            // Do something with the time chosen by the user
            Log.e(TAG, "time picked = hourOfDay = " + hourOfDay + " minute = " + minute);



            hourFrom = hourOfDay;
            minuteFrom = minute;
            Log.e(TAG, "minuteFrom in onTimeSet = " + minuteFrom);

            DateTime dtDate = new DateTime(yearFrom, monthFrom + 1, dayFrom, hourFrom, minuteFrom);
            DateTimeFormatter df = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd-MMM-YYYY HH:MM");
            String date = df.print(dtDate);
            Log.e(TAG, "formatted From date = " + date);




        }
    }




    public void showTimePickerFromDialog(View v) {
        DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFromFragment();
        newFragment.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
    }
```

.

```
08-21 15:00:44.532 10076-10076/com.carefreegroup.rr3 E/ShowRequestLeaveFragment: time picked = hourOfDay = 4 minute = 30
08-21 15:00:44.532 10076-10076/com.carefreegroup.rr3 E/ShowRequestLeaveFragment: minuteFrom in onTimeSet = 30
08-21 15:00:44.532 10076-10076/com.carefreegroup.rr3 E/ShowRequestLeaveFragment: formatted From date = 21-Aug-2017 04:08
```

Comment: The first log of the method returns an incorrect minute too? Or just the last one?

Comment: @cristianorbs I've just done some further testing and copied my logs to the post. The current time where i am is 3:00 and i selected 4:30. it seems the minutes are always set to 08 all the time.

Comment: @cristianorbs sorry, i found what the problem was. The Joda DateTime formatter was wrong. i had mis-spelt the format. for minutes i had 'MM' where is should have been 'mm' to indicate minutes. i think 'MM' means months which would always be 08 as it is august. sorry again :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Try this

---

```
public  void StartTimeShowDialogTime()
{
    final StringBuilder sb_time = new StringBuilder();
    final AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    View view1 = View.inflate(this, R.layout.dialog_time_picker, null);
    mBuilder.setCancelable(false);
    mBuilder.setView(view1);
    Button btn_cancel = view1.findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel);
    Button btn_okey = view1.findViewById(R.id.btn_okay);
    final TimePicker timepicker = view1.findViewById(R.id.tp_timepicker);
    Calendar currentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    int_hour = currentTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int_minute = currentTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    timepicker.setOnTimeChangedListener(new TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            int_hour = hourOfDay;
            int_minute = minute;
            if(int_hour<10) {

                int_hour = Integer.parseInt("0" + int_hour);
           //                    Toast.makeText(Reschedule.this, 
              ""+int_hour, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
    btn_cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            alertDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    btn_okey.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            str_tempstarttime=String.valueOf(int_hour+":"+int_minute);
            str_24HoursStartTime=str_tempstarttime;
            Log.e("TimeS>>",""+str_tempstarttime);
            /*
            to convert 24 hrs to 12 hrs with a,p
             */
            try
            {
                if (int_hour >= 12)
                {
                    if (int_hour == 12) {
                        sb_time.append(12).append(":").append(String.format("%02d", int_minute)).append("p");

                    } else {
                        sb_time.append(int_hour - 12).append(":").append(String.format("%02d", int_minute)).append("p");

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (int_hour == 12) {
                        sb_time.append(12).append(":").append(String.format("%02d", int_minute)).append("a");

                    } else{
                        sb_time.append(int_hour).append(":").append(String.format("%02d", int_minute)).append("a");
                    }

                }
               /*HERE IS YOUR SELECTED TIME*/
                Log.e("Print",""+sb_time);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            alertDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    alertDialog = mBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

---

Comment: it is ok now thanks, i have left a comment above. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Add with your logic

```
Calendar mcurrentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        TimePickerDialog mTimePicker;
        mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(CheckAvailabilityActivity.this, R.style.TimePickerTheme, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
                setTime(selectedHour + ":" + selectedMinute);
            }
        }, hour, minute, false);//Yes 24 hour time
        mTimePicker.show();
```